# get inputs from specific keyboard (USB port) just in my APP even when its not focused

Tags: c#, winforms

### The situation :

I have two Keyboards connected to a single computer (both with USB cable).

### Two problems :

1. How can I get keyboard inputs when my application is not focused
2. Get all inputs from specific keyboard and block its inputs for other
   applications.

I want **two Users** to work with **one Computer** with **two `Keyboard`s**, one works just with my application, with one specific Keyboard and another user, can use the other Keyboard while working with the other software. Keyboard ports never changes. 
is it possible friends ? and how can i do that?

Comment: I am not sure if you can differentiate between the keyboards. but it should be possible to read input and prevent it from getting delivered to other apps using system hooks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx  And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx . To be honest why do you need two keyboards if there is only one person. Maybe some key bindings like vim or Emacs might do the trick.

Comment: thanks for reply, there are two person, one of them never see monitor and just work with one keyboard to call numbers in a queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

I used this for a project a while back, this should do it.